# Server not updating products attribute

Tags: magento-1.9, product-attribute

When updating products attributes to visible on Main Page, server doesn't save the settings.

That might be the problem that the products do not show on homepage.

I added this to the homepage:

```
{{block type="catalog/product_list" name="home.catalog.product.list"
    alias="products_homepage" template="catalog/product/list.phtml"}}
```

Any help?

Magento 1.9.0.1
portuguese-brazil language

Comment: Are you trying to show products on the homepage? Or what is your purpose? If so then try this one
{{block type="catalog/product_list" name="product_list" category_id="YOURCATEGORYID"  template="catalog/product/list.phtml"}}

Comment: I just put it as answer. If thats what you were looking for then please select it as answer

Comment: Jack if that worked could you accept the answer please?

Comment: Well, creating a category and using this as home page products is a solution, but changing the attribute to visible on home page used to work on our server before. Just now it won't change the attributes if I update them. All products where importet.

Answer (score 4):

Are you trying to show products on the homepage? Or what is your purpose? If so then try this one

`{{block type="catalog/product_list" name="product_list" category_id="YOURCATEGORYID" template="catalog/product/list.phtml"}}`